# Почему видео не отображается на телефоне android?

Tags: css, html5, видео

Вот такой код видео, на компьютере отображается, а в телефоне Nexus 5, нет

```html
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" webkit-playsinline="" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; max-height: 480px;">
  <source src="http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.webm" type="video/webm">    
</video>
```

Пример на [сайте](http://timegif.ru/2016/12/28/sistemy-kompanii-trackingpoint-sovmestila-s-google-stekla/)

Comment: возможно проблема в редиректе адресов видео, т.е. http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.mp4 редиретит на http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.gifv человека. Причем если выполнить код здесь с компа и скопировать адрес видео, то он будет .mp4 А для мобильников (возможно) и если самому перейти по адресу, то перекидывает на  .gifv.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это из-за того, что в мобильных браузерах несколько иная политика безопасности, которая, в частности, запрещает автозагрузку видео. Воспроизведение возможно только после клика пользователя по плееру (в андройд можно обойти, в ios пока нельзя [ios video policy](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)). Попробуйте:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('player');

video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

```html
<video id="player" autobuffer>
  <source src="http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Не помогло, возможно проблема в редиректе адресов видео, т.е. http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.mp4 редиретит на http://i.imgur.com/YhTmK3s.gifv человека. Причем если выполнить код здесь с компа и скопировать адрес видео, то он будет .mp4 А для мобильников и если самому перейти по адресу, то перекидывает на  .gifv.

Comment: а как же ОК реализовали это ? только видео попадает в фокус или в центр экрана как оно без всяких кликов по нему начинает воспроизводится ! ?

Comment: Есть пару хаков, когда можно симулировать пользовательский клик по видео. Это описано [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad), а [здесь](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) есть плагин. Но, это работает не во всех Ios.